# Internal Server Error in CakePHP Password Reset Link

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.1

I am using CakePHP as a backend for one of my ionic app.

This is the code in **Webservicescontroller.php** I am using for sending the reset email to users. Which works fine and users are able to receive reset email.

```
public function forgot_password()
{
    $this->isPostValidate();
    $response = array();
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $keys = array('s', 'email');
        $this->validatePostData($keys);
        $s     = $this->filterData('s');
        $email = $this->filterData('email');
        if (empty($s)) {
            $response["error"]   = true;
            $response["message"] = 'No session exist';
            $this->echoResponse(400, $response);
        }
        $this->validateEmail($email);
        $this->loadModel('User');
        $this->User->recursive = -1;
        $user                  = $this->User->findByEmail($email);
        if (!empty($user)) {
            $passkey = md5(uniqid() . $user['User']['email']);
            $url     = Router::url(array ('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'reset', true)) . '/' . $passkey;
            $timeout = date("F j, Y, H:i", strtotime('+1 hour'));
            if ($this->User->updateAll(
                array('User.link_id' => "'" . $passkey . "'",
                    'User.timeout'       => "'" . $timeout . "'"),
                array('User.id' => $user['User']['id'])
            )) {
                if ($this->sendResetEmail($url, $user)) {
                    $response["error"]   = false;
                    $response["message"] = "We have sent a link on your email address to reset it. It'll valid till one hour.";
                    $this->echoResponse(200, $response);
                }
            }
            $response["error"]   = true;
            $response["message"] = 'Something seems to be wrong, please try again.';
            $this->echoResponse(400, $response);
        } else {
            $response["error"]   = true;
            $response["message"] = 'Email address not found.';
            $this->echoResponse(400, $response);
        }
    }
}

function sendResetEmail($url, $user) {
    $fromEmail = $this->getSettingKey('fromEmail');        
    $email = new CakeEmail();
    $email->template('resetpw');
    $email->emailFormat('both');
    $email->from($fromEmail);
    $email->to($user['User']['email'], $user['User']['firstname']." ".$user['User']['lastname']);
    $email->subject('Reset your password');
    $email->viewVars(['url' => $url, 'username' => $user['User']['username']]);

    if ($email->send()) {
       return true;
    } else {
       return false;
    }
}
```

This is the code in **Userscontroller.php** I am using as a function to reset the password.Which is giving me internal server error

```
public function reset($passkey = null) {
    if ($passkey) {
        $query = $this->User->find('all', ['conditions' => ['User.link_id' => $passkey, 'User.timeout' => time()]]);
        $user = $query->first();
        if ($user) {
            if (!empty($this->request->data)) {
                // Clear passkey and timeout
                $this->request->data['User.link_id'] = null;
                $this->request->data['User.timeout'] = null;
                $user = $this->User->patchEntity($user, $this->request->data);
                if ($this->User->save($user)) {
                    $this->Flash->set(__('Your password has been updated.'));
                    return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'login'));
                } else {
                    $this->Flash->error(__('The password could not be updated. Please, try again.'));
                }
            }
        } else {
            $this->Flash->error('Invalid or expired passkey. Please check your email or try again');
            $this->redirect(['action' => 'password']);
        }
        unset($user->password);
        $this->set(compact('user'));
    } else {
        $this->redirect('/');
    }
}
```

Now if a user clicks the link in the email, he is redirected to a webpage which is giving an **internal server error.** Can anyone please help me out and let me know what I am doing wrong.

**reset.ctp**

```
<style>
title{}
button{
border: 1px solid transparent;
font-size: 25px;
border-radius: 5px;
color: #fff !important;
background-color: #428bca;
border-color: #357ebd;
margin-top: 10px;
}
p{color: red;font-size: 15px;}
.reset-form label{font-size: 15px !important;min-width: 135px;}
</style>
<div class="reset-form">
<?php $this->assign('title', 'Reset Password'); ?>
<div class="users form large-9 medium-8 columns content">
    <?php echo $this->Form->create($user) ?>
    <fieldset>
        <legend><?php echo __('Reset Password') ?></legend>
    <?php
        echo $this->Form->input('new_password', ['required' => true, 'type' => 'password', 'class' => 'input1', 'autofocus' => true]); ?>
        <p class="helper">Passwords must be at least 8 characters</p>
    <?php 
        echo $this->Form->input('confirm_password', ['type' => 'password', 'class' => 'input2', 'required' => true]);
    ?>
    </fieldset>
    <?php echo $this->Form->button(__('Submit')); ?>
    <?php echo $this->Form->end(); ?>
</div>
```

Code is written in Cakephp v 2.1

Comment: Have you enabled debugging in the Cake configuration? Looked in your Cake and Apache error logs? There should be some very clear assistance in there, pointing directly at the line and error.

Comment: Yes I did that but no success

Comment: So you're getting an internal server error, and you have absolutely no idea what the actual error is?